# New Wiley LaTeX style

Tags: fonts, book-design

I really like the new scientific book design used by Wiley. You can find an example [here](http://media.johnwiley.com.au/product_data/excerpt/09/35273066/3527306609.pdf). I would like to use this layout style for my thesis, so I was wondering whether there's something available (perhaps similar to    tufte-book or     classicthesis) implementing this design. If there isn't, any help to identify and code the used fonts, header styles, page numbering style etc. would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I think the best option is to start reading the manual of the `memoir` documentclass, this provides immense, well documented, flexibility in designing your book layout.

Comment: Before you do that, check the submission requirements of your institution. There's no point spending time formatting it as you wish only to find you have to abide by a set of specific institutional guidelines in order to have your work accepted.

Comment: Hey! The sample PDF is about latex! ;-) The layout itself has no particular difficulties, but your question is, I'm afraid, too broad.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Since the old Wiley book templates are easy to find online, I was hoping someone might know where I could find the new one. If, for some reason, this would not be available anywhere, I'd be very happy already if someone could show me how to get even just the page numbering right, for example. I'm not such a great LaTeX wizard, unfortunately ;)

Comment: The referenced document isn't set with LaTeX (despite the subject matter:-) it is set with 3b2 (now known as APP) http://www.ptc.com/product/arbortext/advanced-print-publisher

Answer (score 1):

The text in the sample you linked is in FF Scala and the headings are in FF Scala Sans, which you could use with LuaTeX and fontspec.

These are both great typefaces, but unfortunately they have only a few basic mathematical symbols and lack a full Greek alphabet, so they might not be the best choice if you have a lot of maths in your thesis. Finding truly harmonious matches would be pretty hard, and the solution Wiley's cobbled together isn't great (notice, e.g., that "ϕ" in displayed and inline formulas has been borrowed from different typefaces).